# Is it possible to set/insert a new variable in $_GET | $_POST | $_SESSION | $_COOKIE from TWIG?

Tags: php, symfony, session, twig

I have a requirement which which might require me to set a new variable in TWIG for

- `{{ app.request.query }}` i.e. ($_GET)
- `{{ app.request.request }}` i.e. ($_POST)
- `{{ app.request.session }}` i.e. ($_SESSION)
- `{{ app.request.cookies }}` i.e. ($_COOKIE)

e.g. `{% app.request.query.set('myvariable':'value' %}` ...

Comment: Why do you need to do that? There has to be a better solution.

Comment: @Maerlyn I have a twig file in which I have to use a twig variable set in the {body block} in my {javascript block}. As the blocks limit the scope of variables and setting the variable globally does not let me get the value from within the {body block} into my {javascript block}, I have to find alternatives to get what I need done. Hence the usage of set/add for request/session in twig.

Comment: That kind of logic should go in your controller, or a twig extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set the variable while in TWIG here is what I know:

```
For $_POST variables use this :
{{ app.request.request.add(['var1', 'data1']) }}
{{ app.request.request.get(0) }}
{{ app.request.request.get(1) }}

For $_GET variables use this :
{{ app.request.query.add(['var2', 'data2']) }}
{{ app.request.query.get(0) }}
{{ app.request.query.get(1) }}

For $_COOKIE variables use this :
{{ app.request.cookies.add(['var3' , 'data3']) }}
{{ app.request.cookies.get(0) }}
{{ app.request.cookies.get(1) }}

For $_SESSION variables use this :
{{ app.session.set('var4', 'data4') }}
{{ app.session.get('var4') }} <!-- shows 'data4 -->
Or
{{ app.request.session.set('var4', 'data4') }}
{{ app.request.session.get('var4') }} # shows 'data4
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I will wait to accept this answer for a day for two so that if someone else wants to add more information they have a chance.

Answer (score -1):

You can easy append element to the array before calling Twig->render in PHP.

Simply write

```
$_GET['myvariable'] = $value
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am looking for an answer to set the variables from within TwigBundle (Symfony).